# MATLAB: How to find the coordinates of the repeating elements?

Tags: matlab, duplicates

I have two column vectors X and Y of the same size derived by following Matlab code:

```
mask = im2bw(rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES8w1.jpg')));
separation = bwulterode(mask,'euclidean',[0 0 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 0]).*mask; 
[X, Y] = find(separation);
imshow(mask); hold on; plot(Y, X, '.r');
```

Each element in X has a corresponding element in Y. I removed the repeating values in X and also their correspondent values in Y using this code (by @VHarisop):

```
% 'stable' argument preserves ordering
[Xfixed, ind] = unique(X, 'stable');
% ind now holds the indices of the unique elements
Yfixed = Y(ind);
```

I need to find the coordinates of the repeating elements: the elements of X and Y that are not in Xfixed and Yfixed respectively. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ind` contains the **first** locations of each unique value in `Xfixed`, simply create a vector that goes from 1 up to as long as `X` is, and use `ind` to eliminate those entries from this vector.  The result of this will be a vector that will contain the non-unique entries in `Xfixed`.  As such, try doing:

```
val = 1 : numel(X);
val(ind) = [];
Xfinal = X(val);
Yfinal = Y(val);
```

The first two lines of code is exactly what I talked about from before.  `val` will contain those indices that do not contain unique elements.  We would then use `val` to index into `X` and `Y` to grab our content and these are stored into `Xfinal` and `Yfinal`.

---

Here's an example:

```
X = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8]; %// Example data
Y = [9 8 7 6 5 4 2 1 3 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 8 0 0];

[Xfixed, ind] = unique(X, 'stable');  %// Your code

%// New code
val = 1 : numel(X);
val(ind) = [];
Xfinal = X(val);
Yfinal = Y(val);
```

Showing what `val`, `Xfinal` and `Yfinal` are, we get:

```
>> Xfinal

Xfinal =

     1     1     2     3     3     4     5     6     7     7     8

>> Yfinal

Yfinal =

     8     7     5     2     1     5     7     9     8     8     0

>> val

val =

     2     3     5     7     8    10    12    14    16    17    19
```

If we also examine `ind`, we get:

```
ind =

     1
     4
     6
     9
    11
    13
    15
    18
```

`ind` contains those entries that are unique and were encountered the first time.  This means that `val` contains those other entries that were not unique.  You would use `val` to index into `X` and `Y` to retrieve those non-unique values.  If you look at `val` and compare this with each corresponding location in `X`, you will see that these correspond to the non-unique locations and we select these out from `X` and the corresponding positions in `Y`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help as always :)

Answer (score 1):

The final three lines find the complement of the full index list and the indices provided by the unique function.

```
mask = im2bw(rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES8w1.jpg')));

separation = bwulterode(mask,'euclidean',[0 0 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 0]).*mask; 

[X, Y] = find(separation);

imshow(mask); hold on; plot(Y, X, '.r');

[Xfixed, ind] = unique(X, 'stable');

Yfixed = Y(ind);

ind_repeat=setdiff(1:1:size(X,1),ind);

Xrepeat=X(ind_repeat);

Yrepeat=Y(ind_repeat);
```

Comment: Nice job on `setdiff`.  However, if I can nitpick, I would recommend you use `numel` instead of `size(X,1)`.  If the input to `find` was a 1D row vector, then the output will also be a row vector and not a column vector, as that is what `size(X,1)` is implying.  Either way, very nice.